# Read several ASCII characters and get the value

Tags: c, ascii

Can someone explain or correct me on the code i have?
I'm trying to input several characters and get the ascii value

ex: input: ab; output:9798

This is my code but there's a 10 at the end of it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    char c;
    printf("Enter any character\n");

    for (c=0; c<=122; c++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%d",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `10` would be the line-feed left by the enter-key you pressed after entering your characters.

Comment: how to i take it off?

Comment: How about `if(c==10) { break; }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Also, please learn to format your code in a more orthodox style. The standard styles are there to make it easier to read code. Using a standard style makes it easier for others to read your code, and you are posting code for public consumption. It is also a good idea to post syntactically correct code; you can't put the `int main()` etc on the same line as the `#include`. (Someone else reformatted your code for you while I was typing.) You should type your code without tabs, copy'n'paste to SO, select it, and use **`{}`** to indent.

Comment: @hyde: no — that's not a good idea.  `if (c == '\n') break;` would be a better idea, or `if (isprint(c)) printf("%d", c);`, which requires `#include <ctype.h>` too, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the `isprint` is probably not what OP wants, considering he's printing ASCII codes of whatever user types. `'\n'` is better, but then again the whole program could be better, and I was trying to lead the OP to a "how do I stop it from printing 10" kinda train of thought.

Comment: Put a space before you print each number as in `printf(" %d",c);` to see that an input of `ab` results in " 97 98".

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [ASCII table](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html), a decimal value of `10` is a newline character. In other words, you process `\n` character as part of the input. This can happen when user copy-pastes multiple lines, or when <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, for example. If you do not want that to happen, you need to take extra care to ignore `\n`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    char c;
    printf("Enter any character\n");

    for (c=0; c<=122; c++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == '\n')
            break; /* Or perhaps continue? Depends on what you actually want. */
        printf("%d",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that different systems may have different conventions as for what newline actually is. On UNIX, it is `\n` character only, on Windows, it might be a combination or `\r` and `\n`. So if you want to make your program portable, this needs to be taken into account. You can either do it yourself, or use some other library (GNU [getline](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) comes to mind). You can read more about newline [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: I think that c=='n' should follow the scanf... be in the middle between scanf and printf... to avoid printing the "10".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to exclude some chars from the output and not only '\n', in that case you can try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isEndingChar(char c) {
   char terminators[3] = {'\r','\t','\n'}
   int n;
   for( n=0; n<3; n++ ) {
      if( terminators[i]==c )
         return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() { 
   char c;
   printf("Enter any character\n");
   for (c=0; c<=122; c++)
   {
      scanf("%c", &c);
      if( isEndingChar( c ) )
        break;
      printf("%d",c);
   }
   return 0;
}
```